# Notepad++ RegEx : Shuffle text and paste

Tags: regex, notepad++

I try to shuffle this word in notepad++ with RegEx:

```
word1|word2|word3|word4|word5
```

and Result is :

```
word2|word1|word3|word4|word5
word3|word1|word2|word4|word5
word4|word1|word3|word2|word5
word5|word1|word3|word4|word2
```

Can notepad++ do that?

Comment: You want Notepad++ to generate precisely four lines with the tuff between the | character in a random permutation?

Comment: @doctorlove yes sir ...can you explain me how it works ?

Comment: Notepad++ is a text editor, it can't do such things. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: You could do this with http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/ but why not just use some online code tool. Eg with php [see this demo @ eval.in](https://eval.in/1110273) and copy output to your editor.

Comment: @Toto yes sir, thanks for advice ...

Comment: @bobblebubble wow, thank you so much sir ... it's really help me ...

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just capture the words and output them:

Search: `^(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)$`
Regex mode
Replace: `\2|\1|\3|\4|\5\r\n\3|\1|\2|\4|\5\r\n\4|\1|\3|\2|\5\r\n\5|\1|\3|\4|\2`

But if you want something more general (ie. variable number of words, generating *all* permutations rather than specific ones, etc) then you will need a script of some kind. Personally, I'd whip up a quick and dirty PHP script to do the job, but others may use Node, Python, etc. - plenty of options.